# Cannot add table to context - LINQ-To-SQL

Tags: linq-to-sql, datacontext

I'd be happy to give you more info if you need, just ask for it.

I have in my database a table of articles, a table of tags and a link table. The article table has values like Id, Subject etc etc, the tags only have Id and Tag. The link has TagId and ArticleId.

The problem is that when I drag drop the link-table nothing happens!
This all worked before I decided to rename my column in the tables from "ID" to "Id" to correct spelling.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Rename them back, report your findings, and post your schema please.

Comment: for quick reference I would always generalize your attributes to adhere to your tables, so instead of id i would say articleid, so whenever I use that as a foreign key i know what is referenced back.

I'd rename your tables lowercase.

Comment: Good idea, ill rename the values. However the tables are named lowercase(didn't even include the table names in my posT)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that one of my foreign cas was set to nullable. Unsetting it from nullable made it work!

Comment: Interesting - great that you found solution

Comment: @Sergey however seems like restarting visual studio did the charm as well

Answer (score 0):

Please check that all tables has PK on Id column. 
You are saying that 'The link has TagId and ArticleId.' - For LINQ you need to have single PK - so you need to create fake Primary Key ID (maybe int identity)

Comment: Indeed they do. The link table has a combined PK of TagId and ArticleId

Comment: Do not remember exactly, but COMBINED PK is somthing which worth to avoid in LINQ. for example, here this is accepted answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/647146/is-it-beneficial-to-use-multicolumn-composite-primary-keys-when-using-linq-to-s

Comment: The problem is that I have other combined PK without any problems using LINQ